# Полетный контроллер: Пид делать на каждый мотор или лучше сделать один общий?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

Привет. 
Пишу полётный контроллер для квадрокоптера. Язык Python 3. Платформа Raspberry.
Сейчас застрял на пид регуляторах. Необходима помощь человека, который знает что это такое. 
Суть вопроса. 
Пид делать на каждый мотор или лучше сделать один общий?

Пока что делаю на каждый. Так как считаю это и проще в реализации, и логичнее в плане самих топологии управления.

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понимаю, о чём вы, то, конечно, на каждый мотор пойдёт отдельный регулятор. Моторы у вас разные, могут чуть по разному сбиваться с нужного режима, поэтому управляющие воздействия тоже нужны на разные моторы.

Если у вас будет один регулятор, то явно должны возникнуть проблемы с тем, что у вас есть показания с четырёх датчиков, а регулятору для работы нужен один вход и один выход.

Comment: Если мы используем классический ПИД, то конечно же, на каждый мотор нужен отдельный ПИД. Но с другой стороны, стабилизировать нам надо не столько отдельные двигатели, сколько коптер в целом. А именно, его наклон, скорость, высоту полета. И все это тоже охота повесить на ПИД-регулятор.